# How to plot a mesh .OBJ in an R shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, mesh

I would like to plot a mesh .OBJ in an R shiny application.

I tried with the "rgl" package.
In an R script this works perfectly well. The following code

```
library(rgl)

mesh <- readOBJ("cow.obj")
shade3d(mesh, color = "green")
```

gives an interactive plot in the "Viewer" window.

[image: Mesh .OBJ plot in the Viewer window of R Studio]

But when I try to integrate it in an R shiny application with the following code

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)

options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    rglwidgetOutput("mesh")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  save <- options(rgl.inShiny = TRUE)
  on.exit(options(save))
  
  output$mesh <- renderRglwidget({
    try(rgl.close())
    mesh <- readOBJ("cow.obj")
    shade3d(mesh, color = "green")
    rglwidget()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have the error "ERROR: 0:? : " : syntax error".

[image: Error in the R shiny application]

Do you know how to solve it ? Or do you know another way to plot an interactive mesh in an R shiny application ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Are you using the latest version of **rgl**? There was such a bug in the previous version.

Comment: You're totally right... the problem was my version or rgl...

Everything is fine now, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

In order for your code to work, you have to upgrade the **rgl** package.

Alternatively, you can read the `.obj` file with `rgl::readOBJ`, and use the `r3js` package to plot it in a Shiny app.

```r
cyclide   <- rgl::readOBJ("cyclide.obj")
vertices  <- t(cyclide[["vb"]][-4L, ])
triangles <- t(cyclide[["it"]])
normals   <- t(cyclide[["normals"]])

library(r3js)
data3js <- plot3js(
  xlim = range(vertices[, 1L]),
  ylim = range(vertices[, 2L]),
  zlim = range(vertices[, 3L]),
  label_axes = c("x", "y", "z"),
  aspect = c(1, 1, 1)
)
data3js <- shape3js(
  data3js,
  vertices = vertices,
  faces    = triangles,
  normals  = normals,
  col = "firebrick"
)

# shiny app ####
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  r3jsOutput("cyclide")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["cyclide"]] <- renderR3js({
    r3js(data3js)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]